# I want to it possible to create data only with my account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I can't pass rspec's test.

I want to make it possible for only my account to create academic history.

But when I test that other account can't make academic history,

```
   describe 'POST /v1/accounts/:account_id/academic_histories' do
        let(:account) { create(:account) }
        let(:headers) { { Authorization: "Bearer #{account.jwt}" } }
        subject(:request) { post v1_account_academic_histories_path(target_account.id), params: params, headers: headers }
        let(:params) { { academic_history: attributes_for(:academic_history) } }
        
        context "Other's account" do
          let(:target_account) { create(:account) }
    
          it "can't create academic history" do
            expect { request }.not_to change(AcademicHistory, :count)
            expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
          end
        end
      end
```

Rspec showed error.

```
Failures:

  1) V1::AcademicHistories POST /v1/accounts/:account_id/academic_histories Other's account can't create academic history
     Failure/Error: expect { request }.not_to change(AcademicHistory, :count)
       expected `AcademicHistory.count` not to have changed, but did change from 0 to 1
     # ./spec/requests/v1/academic_histories_request_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.69 seconds (files took 3.06 seconds to load)
17 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/v1/academic_histories_request_spec.rb:36 # V1::AcademicHistories POST /v1/accounts/:account_id/academic_histories Other's account can't create academic history
```

Why can other account make academic history

> expected `AcademicHistory.count` not to have changed, but did change from 0 to 1

I don't know How to pass this Rspec's test

models/ability.ts

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
# Ability
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(account)
    account ||= Account.new
    can :read, Account
    can :manage, Account, id: account.id
    can :manage, Profile, account_id: account.id
    can :read, AcademicHistory
    can :manage, AcademicHistory, account_id: account.id
  end
end
```

academic_histories_controller.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
module V1
  # AcademicHistoriesController
  class AcademicHistoriesController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :account
    load_and_authorize_resource through: :account, shallow: true

    def create
      @academic_history.save!
      render json: @academic_history, status: :created
    end

    private

    def resource_params
      params.require(:academic_history).permit(
        :name,
        :faculty,
        :since_date,
        :until_date,
        :type
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please check for which account jwt token is getting generated and passed in headers? Because in my opinion, this is possible only when the authorized account is creating history. It is not clear from code to me, why in headers account.jwt is passed? Shouldn't it should be target.jwt?

Comment: Set your target account ID to a hard coded value - and test if it should fail?